# How to set tabbarcontroller viewControllers conditionally?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tabbarcontroller in my app. So its filled with 5 viewcontroller initially when the app is loaded. Supposed I am on the first index viewcontroller and I set a value. Depending on the value i have set when I click on the 4th item in the tabbarcontroller it should display specific viewcontroller. How to do that?

Comment: what you want exactly?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to post the notification.

Other way is to set the selection value in some global variable and refer it while displayng the view controller of tab 4.